# KnockoutJS Dynamic CheckBox Binding

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js

I have a list of attributes with different datatype, if the datatype is a check box then i would like the bind the value in string to checkbox. I managed to bind the value from database to UI. But if there is any modification to the value, I could not capture it back from the list. Could anyone advice on this?

Thanks.

UI Code

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: data().Attributes">
        <tr>
          <th data-bind="text: AttributeName"></th>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="if: AttributeDataType === 'CheckBox'">
                    <input class="input-sm" type="checkbox" data-bind="value: AttributeValue, checked: $parent.ConvertToBoolean(AttributeValue), visible: $parent.editMode() " />
                </span>
                <span data-bind="if: AttributeDataType === 'Text'">
                    <input class="input-sm" type="text" data-bind="value: AttributeValue, visible: $parent.editMode() " style="min-width: 300px;" />
                </span>
                <span data-bind="if: AttributeDataType === 'DropDown'">
                    <select class="selectpicker" data-bind="options: $parent.availableTestProgramType, value: AttributeValue, visible: $parent.editMode() "></select>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Script

```
 public data = ko.observable<any>([]);
public ConvertToBoolean = (x: string) => {
  return x == "true" ? true : false;  }
```

Comment: Is `AttributeValue` declared as an observable?

Comment: Hi Neps, the data is declared as an observable. Do I need to declare AttributeValue as an observable separately? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you want to "capture it back from the list". Otherwise, it's just one-way binding _to_ the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to resolved my problem by adding click event to the checkbox and change the underlying data value.

UI Code

```
 <input class="input-sm" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.ConvertToBoolean(AttributeValue), visible: $parent.editMode(), click: $parent.toggleAssociation " />
```

Script

```
public toggleAssociation = function (item) {
  if (item.AttributeValue == "" || item.AttributeValue == "false") {
      item.AttributeValue = "true";
  } else {
      item.AttributeValue = "false";
  }
  return true;
```

}